# calabash-android 0.4.6 performAction doesnt work

Tags: android, calabash

I have had to update my script to use extend Calabash::Android::Operations instead of include Calabash::Android::Operations. I did this to make it running in the Jenkins using lesspainful service.However now when i run  wait_for_elements_exist() or performAction() from my code it errors out with

undefined method `wait_for_elements_exist' for # (NoMethodError)

Has anyone faced this.?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead of simple `performAction`:

```
default_device.performAction(...)
```